# How to disable automatic bullets in Quill

Tags: quill

Just started using Quill and find it very useful.  My projects require plain text editing.  Specifically I'm using quill as a form to enter YAML code.  The dash, "-", is a key item in YAML.  The problem is Quill automatically formats the line as a bullet.

Is there a way to disable automatic bullets?

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/ there doesn't appear to be a way to disable a specific format, but you may be able to simply create a list of all formats and remove the `list` format.

Comment: could you expand on that? Did that in my quill, but it still keeping to automatically format stuff...

Comment: I also want to disable automatic list creation, as I am struggling with this issue: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2408. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the comments, whitelist things you'll allow in the "formats" option (not the toolbar area)

```
var editor = new quill("#someElemId", {
        modules: {
            toolbar: [
                'bold', 
                //{ 'list': 'bullet' }, 
                { 'indent': '-1'}, 
                { 'indent': '+1' }, 
                { 'color': ['black', 'red', 'blue', 'green'] }, 
                'link', 
                'clean'
            ]
        },
        formats : [
            "background",
            "bold", 
            "color", 
            "font", 
            "code", 
            "italic", 
            "link", 
            "size", 
            "strike", 
            "script",
            "underline", 
            "blockquote", 
            // "header",
            "indent", 
            // "list", <-- commented-out to suppress auto bullets
            "align", 
            "direction", 
            "code-block", 
            "formula", 
            "image",
            "video"
        ],
        theme: 'snow', // snow   bubble
    });
```

Comment: When 'list' is removed then bullets toolbar button is not working for me. What do I need to make bullet button still work?

Comment: Not sure you can do anything about that :( Catch-22

Answer (score 5):

Quill's built in [Keyboard module](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/modules/keyboard.js#L470) is responsible for auto formatting lists. You can override or disable this behavior by importing and extending the keyboard module like so.

```js
var Keyboard = Quill.import('modules/keyboard');

class CustomKeyboard extends Keyboard {
 static DEFAULTS = {
  ...Keyboard.DEFAULTS,
  bindings: {
   ...Keyboard.DEFAULTS.bindings,
    ['list autofill']: undefined,
  }
 }
}

Quill.register('modules/keyboard', CustomKeyboard);
```

If you still list detection for other input ("* " for example), you can change the regex that the 'list autofill' binding matches like so

```js
var Keyboard = Quill.import('modules/keyboard');

class CustomKeyboard extends Keyboard {
 static DEFAULTS = {
  ...Keyboard.DEFAULTS,
  bindings: {
   ...Keyboard.DEFAULTS.bindings,
    ['list autofill']: {
     ...Keyboard.DEFAULTS.bindings['list autofill'],
     prefix: /^\s*?(\d+\.|\*|\[ ?\]|\[x\])$/
    },
  }
 }
}

Quill.register('modules/keyboard', CustomKeyboard);
```

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/josephdangerstewart/pen/dyNEGoj

Further documentation on Modules can be found on the Quill website: https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/#extending

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
modules: {
  keyboard: {
    bindings: {
      'list autofill': {
        prefix: /^\s*()$/
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will ignore *automatically* ordered lists.
However, you still use bullets manually, by clicking the indent command or using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.